# Gathering every sentence in one line after a specific sign

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some expressions and I want to gather them in a line after dot.

for example:

> $In $dem anfang war daswort . vnnd daswort war bey Gott , vnd Gott war daswort , dasselb war $yn $dem anfang bey Gott , Alleding sind durch dasselb gemacht , vnnd on dasselb ist nichts gemacht was gemacht ist , Jn yhm war dasleben , vnd dasleben war eyn liecht dermenschen , vnd dasliecht scheynet ynn diefinsternis , vnd diefinsternis $haben $es nicht begriffen . Es wart eyn mensch , von Gott gesand , der hies Johannes , derselb kam $zu $dem zeugnis , das er von demliecht zeugete , auff das siealle durch yhn glewbten , Er war nicht dasliecht , sondern das er zeugete von demliecht , Das war eyn warhafftigs liecht , wilchs allemenschen erleucht , durch seyn zu=kunfft ynn disewellt , Es war ynn derwellt , vnd diewellt ist durch dasselb gemacht , vnd diewellt kandt es nicht .

and I want change it form to this one after dot:

```
  $In $dem anfang war daswort . 


  vnnd daswort war bey Gott , vnd Gott war daswort , dasselb war $yn $dem anfang bey Gott , Alleding sind durch dasselb gemacht , vnnd on dasselb ist nichts gemacht was gemacht ist , Jn yhm war dasleben , vnd dasleben war eyn liecht dermenschen , vnd dasliecht scheynet ynn diefinsternis , vnd diefinsternis $haben $es nicht begriffen .

  Es wart eyn mensch , von Gott gesand , der hies Johannes , derselb kam $zu $dem zeugnis , das er von demliecht zeugete , auff das siealle durch yhn glewbten , Er war nicht dasliecht , sondern das er zeugete von demliecht , Das war eyn warhafftigs liecht , wilchs allemenschen erleucht , durch seyn zu=kunfft ynn disewellt , Es war ynn derwellt , vnd diewellt ist durch dasselb gemacht , vnd diewellt kandt es nicht .
```

I test this :

```
find for: .

replace with: .\r\n
```

But all the characters were changed to dot.

Could you help me?

Comment: Thank you all.
the problem is solved, now. 
 thanks for you comments.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a regex [metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) that matches any character except linebreaks. If you're looking for literal dots, you need to escape them:

Search for `\.` and replace as usual.

Answer (score 0):

the dot is the 'one character wildcard' in regex.

just escape it with a backslash like `\.`

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?\.)
```

This should do it.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9zP6/2